# Can't get id of a dynamically added component with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a `v-for` loop that populates `<audio>` components backed by an array of blobs and the buttons to play and delete it.

```html
<div v-for="(file, index) in soundFiles" :key="index">
  <audio :src="file.url" :id="file.uuid" :ref="el => audios[file.uuid] = el" />{{ file.name }}&nbsp;
  <button :id="file.uuid" v-on:click="playSound">&gt;</button>
  <button :id="file.uuid" v-on:click="deleteSound">X</button>
</div>
```

The way `:ref` is used is taken from [this example](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/refs-and-the-vue-3-composition-api/)

```js
const soundFiles = ref([]);
const audios = ref([]);
//......
function playSound(e) {
  const soundId = e.target.id;
  audios.value[soundId].play();
}
```

When I add a sound and then click the play button I get an empty soundId. The inspector also shows that the audio and buttons don't have any attributes. When I reload the page the data is pulled from the local storage, the underlying array for v-for is populated in the setup() function and the elements are created with attributes just fine.
What should I do to set the ids of my elements dynamically?

Comment: *The inspector also shows that the audio and buttons don't have any attributes* ...sounds strange. How exactly do you "add a sound" to the `soundFiles` array ?

Comment: ```javasript
async function fileChanged(event) {
const files = event.target.files;
const file = files[0];
soundFiles.value.push({
  name: file.name,
  url: URL.createObjectURL(file),
  uuid: file.uuid
});
```

Comment: There was a problem: file doesn't have an uuid field and I tried to access it. I've fixed it and the array fills up as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div v-for="(file, index) in soundFiles" :key="index">
  <audio :src="file.url" :id="file.uuid" :ref="el => audios[file.uuid] = el" />{{ file.name }}&nbsp;
  <button :id="file.uuid" v-on:click="playSound(file.uuid)">&gt;</button>
  <button :id="file.uuid" v-on:click="deleteSound">X</button>
</div>
```

```
function playSound(id) {
  audios.value[id].play();
}
```

Why don't you write it like that?

Comment: I tried this approach and the id parameter I get in the playSound function is undefined

Comment: Actually, the problem was with adding files to the list, I forgot to set the uuid. This approach now works.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use index as v-for key if you add anything dynamically, make the key ID. If your data don't have id as default, add it on the fly in computed property:

```
<div v-for="file in files" :key="file.id"></div>

data() {
  return {
    soundFiles: [ array of your files ],
  }
},
computed: {
  files() {
    return soundFiles.map(x => {
      x.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000)
      return x;
    })
  }
}
```